# Separate 'plant species' into different line graphs

Tags: r, graph, line

For my master internship in ecology I am trying to plot the proportion of germinated seeds over time for different plant species in different soil types.

I want to make a separate line plot for each species, with a line for each soil type (11 in total).

Does anyone know how I can plot x Day_since_cooling and y = Proportion_germination, colour = Soil_origin  for each plant species a separate graph? I do not know how to split the plant species ('Species') into separate graphs (5 in total).

I unfortunately cannot attach the data frame in this message, as it has too many characters (67103!).
Hopefully someone can give me advice without it!

Thank you for your time.

````
structure(list(Soil_origin = c("P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", 
"P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", 
"P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c"), Species = c("C_flava", 
"C_flava", "C_flava", "C_flava", "C_flacca", "C_flacca", "C_flacca", 
"C_flacca", "C_panicea", "C_panicea", "C_panicea", "C_panicea", 
"S_pratensis", "S_pratensis", "S_pratensis", "S_pratensis", "L_perenne", 
"L_perenne", "L_perenne", "L_perenne"), Pot = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), Date = structure(c(1685664000, 
1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
1685664000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    Day_since_cooling = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), Total_start = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10), Germinated = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Proportion_germination = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Comment_competition = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")) ```
````

Comment: Hi Stefanie! Can you do a `dput(head(df, 20)` (or whatever would be a non-overwhelming amount of data)? And can you include the code you have so far? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately I cannot enter the code without Stack Overflow giving me an error... I used the insert code option, but it however does not work.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: Hi Mark, hereby the error: ''Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.''

Comment: Paste in the code, then wrap the whole thing between \`\`\`s i.e. \`\`\`print("hello world\`\`\`

Comment: As you can see, I was able to insert the function, but not the output. Strange...

Comment: Did you copy the output from the console? You should copy that and paste it

Comment: I can't help you if you can't paste your code or your data. Just paste it in raw if it's the only way

Comment: It worked! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Cool! thanks for that! Have you already written any code? e.g. with ggplot?

Comment: Hi Mark, I did write some code for a similar line plot, however, not for this particular question. This is the code I used for the other line plot: ggplot(Data_petrischaal_R, aes(x = Day, y = Proportion_germination, colour = Species)) +
  geom_line() + labs(x = "Time (days)", y = "Proportion of germinated seeds") + theme_classic() + ylim (0.0, 1.0)